# Rails Render partial through ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, render

I can't seem to load the HTML, I am getting 200 status, and server shows a success process, still can't seem to execute anything inside the .js.erb file.

**Link button to call partial:** `<a> data-target="#user-form-modal" class="register-btn" data-remote="true" data-toggle="modal" data-user-type="1" href="/home/remote_sign_up">Student</a>`

**Route:** `get 'home/remote_sign_up', to: 'home#remote_sign_up', as: 'home_remote_sign_up'`

**home/remote_sign_up.js.erb**

```
if($('.modal').length > 0) {
    $("#user-form-modal").modal();
}
else {
    $("body").prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'remote_sign_up') %>");
    $("#user-form-modal").modal();
}
```

**home/_remote_sign_up.slim** I have my modal here in which I'm calling.

**home_controller.rb**

```
respond_to :html, :json, :js

def index
  @subjects = Subject.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: Subject.all.pluck(:name) }
  end
end

def remote_sign_up
 respond_to :js
end
```

**application_controller.rb** I have this declared: `protect_from_forgery with: :exception`

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:37815
Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 27 Feb 2015 16:36:48 GMT
Etag:"86956ed8c50442138977628b146e1d80"
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.2/2014-05-08)
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Meta-Request-Version:0.3.4
X-Request-Id:11ec0be3-1899-407e-baec-f17b4870ab86
X-Runtime:0.253766
X-Xss-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Preview:

```
0: 58
1: 58
2: 58
3: "><div class="
4: "><div class="
5: "><button class="
6: " data-target="
7: -1
8: " data-toggle="
9: " type="
10: "><span class="
11: ">Toggle navigation</span><span class="
12: "></span><span class="
13: "></span><span class="
14: "></span></button><a class="
15: " href="
```

Response:

```
if($('.modal').length > 0) {
    $("#user-form-modal").modal();
}
else {
    $("body").prepend(Modal code here);
    $("#user-form-modal").modal();
}
```

A part of the preview I'm recieving

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After further looking at code, found the real bug.

Try adding `format.js` to your respond_to block. And add it to a remote_sign_up method.

So it would look like this:

```
def remote_sign_up
  @subjects = Subject.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: Tried, even adding a remote_sign_up method and manually adding respond_to block and still won't work, same status though. I'll post the response.

Comment: Hmmm...time to debug a bit then. Can you replace your js.erb file with something to tell you if the request is at least getting that far? Like an an ```alert("you made it to the js.erb template. yay!")``` . At least then you will know if it is a ruby/rails issue or a js issue.

Comment: Yep, alert didn't fire, though if I add a typo inside the `escape_javascript` it returns 500 status.

Comment: Ah. Just looked over your controller again. You are sending the request here: ```home#remote_sign_up```. That translates into "go to the home controller and hit the remote_sign_up method". Do you have a remote_sign_up method in your controller? I only see the index method?

Comment: I added it while debugging and still gave me the same result, I wrote a respond_to block with js format.

Comment: Try it with the new method in your controller. The alert should/will fire. Can you post the updated controller code so others can see that we have made it that far?

Comment: Posted some of the response too, it though looks like is being rendered without script tags, the code is not even being added into the body.

Comment: You are using ```respond_to :js``` incorrectly in your ```remote_sign_up``` method. Replace the ```respond_to :js``` with a block.  

    ```respond_to do |format|```
        ```format.js```
    ```end```

Comment: Changed it, this is how the response looks like: http://pasteboard.co/1r24SNfY.png

Comment: It looks like the Rails part is done now. Like it is getting from route->controller->method->js.erb file. So we need to work on the js part. I don't think you want to prepend to the body. You want to add the slim template to the modal, then fire off the modal. So it would be:

```$("#user-form-modal").append(Modal code here);```

```$("#user-form-modal").modal();```

Comment: Tried that too, even sending simple HTML inside the render, but no luck :(

Comment: Hmm...Then is a JS issue. I'm not nearly as skilled at debugging those, but what I would do is this: Trim back your JS and rebuild step by step. Start by getting it to fire a simple alert or console message. If it can't do that, try dropping the .erb from the file and just doing a .js. If you can get the simple stuff to fire, then see if you can get a blank modal to fire. If you can do that, then try appending HTML and firing the modal. Just some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took me long to answer, everything is working now, all I had to do was add `thin` as the web server and it worked.